# Angular ng-repeat not working spotify app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ng-repeat does not seem to work

App.js

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', ['jsonService', 'ngRoute', 'ngResource'])

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, JsonService) {
    //JsonService.get(function(data) {
    //   $scope.name = data.artists.href;
    // $scope.children = data.artists.items;
    //}); 

    $scope.searchShow = () => {
        JsonService.search.query({
            show: $scope.showname
        }, (response) => {
            console.log(response);
            //   $scope.name = response.artists.href;

            $scope.children = response;

        })
    } 
    $scope.showDetails = (id) => {
        console.log(id);
        JsonService.detail.get({

            details: id
        }, (response) => {
            console.log(response.items);
            //   $scope.name = response.artists.href;
            $scope.details = response.items;

        })
    }

});
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('')
}])
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/search.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/details', {
            templateUrl: 'views/details.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        })

}])
```

i have two views .A search views which search a artist name and detail view which provides detail.I am able to parse the data to search views and display the result.I am not able to display result to details views

Search.html

```
<div class="search-header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <form>
                    <h2 class="v-center">search</h2>
                    <p class="lead">APi search-You can search for artist,albums,tracks</p>

                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="showname" class="form-control input-md" />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                     <button
                        type="button"
                        class="btn btn-md btn-warning pull-right"
                        ng-click="searchShow()">Search</button>
                  </span>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <div ng-if="children" class="results-block">
                    <div ng-repeat="child in children">



                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <img class=images ng-src="{{child.images[0].url}}" onerror="this.src='./placeholder.png'" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <ul class="list-group">
                                        <li class="list-group-item"><b>Name</b>: {{child.name }}</li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item"><b>Type</b>: {{child.type}}</li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item"><b>Popularity</b>: {{child.popularity}}</li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" ng-click="showDetails(child.id)"><a href="#details">Details</a></button></li>
                                    </ul>

                                </div>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr>
                    <hr>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Details

```
<div ng-repeat="detail in details">



    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img class=images ng-src="{{detail.images[0].url}}" onerror="this.src='./placeholder.png'" />
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <hello></hello>
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item"><b>Name</b>: {{detail.name }}</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><b>Type</b>: {{detail.type}}</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><b>href</b>: {{detail.href}}</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-link"><a href="#">Back</a></button></li>
                </ul>

            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<hr>
<hr>
```

App.js edited

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', ['jsonService', 'ngRoute', 'ngResource'])

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, JsonService) {
    //JsonService.get(function(data) {
    //   $scope.name = data.artists.href;
    // $scope.children = data.artists.items;
    //}); 


    $scope.searchShow = () => {
        JsonService.search.query({
            show: $scope.showname
        }, (response) => {
            console.log(response);
            //   $scope.name = response.artists.href;

            $scope.children = response;

        })
    }
    $scope.showDetails = (id) => {
        console.log(id);
        JsonService.detail.get({

            details: id
        }, (response) => {
            //   console.log(response.data);
            //   $scope.name = response.artists.href;
            $scope.details = response.data;

        })
    }

});

app.controller('DetailCtrl', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    var id = $routeParams.id;
    console.log("Detail controller" + id);
    JsonService.detail.get({

        details: id
    }, (response) => {
        //console.log(response.data);
        $scope.details = response.data;

    })



});



app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('')
}])
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/search.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/details', {
            templateUrl: 'views/details.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/details/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'views/details.html',
            controller: 'DetailCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        })

}])
```

Service.js

```
angular.module('jsonService', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('JsonService', function($resource) {
        return {

            search: $resource('/api/search'),
            detail: $resource('/api/details')
        }
    });
```

routes.js-using node js

```
const
    express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    router = express.Router(),
    superagent = require('superagent')

module.exports = () => {

    router.get('/api/search', (req, res) => {
        const { show } = req.query // this is the same as const show = req.query.show
        console.log(show);
        superagent
            .get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=' + show + ':&type=artist')
            .end((err, response) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    //  console.log(response.body.artists.items);
                    res.json(response.body.artists.items);

                }

            })
    })


    router.get('/api/details', (req, res) => {
        const { details } = req.query // this is the same as const show = req.query.show
        console.log(details);
        superagent
            .get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/' + details + '/albums')
            .end((err, response) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    res.json(response.body);
                    //    console.log(response.body.items);

                }

            })
    })
    router.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/index.html'))
    })

    return router
}
```

Edit:
When i tried to console log $scope.children is returning the value where as $scope.details returns undefined

Comment: you can try change to   `$scope.details = response.data`

Comment: Does response have field "items"?

Comment: yes i do i am able to get console log on response.items

Comment: you should pass data in href and use $routeParams get the data

Comment: Any help on how to do that

Comment: I already have the details method which gets the artist ablums when i click the details link.Since it only get the data when i click the href,i don't know how i can pass the value through it again

Comment: Hard to help a lot without being able to see data structure...create a basic demo in plunker

Comment: @Ash can you share JsonService ?, it could be related to the digest cycle

Comment: i have added both jsonservice and routes from server node js @ShyA

Comment: I am able to route to detail view.I am able display the h1 headers but when i use ng-repeat i  am not able to get anything in detail view

Comment: this doesn't look like an issue with `ng-repeat`, it looks like you are having issues passing a parameter to a new view segment.

Comment: Yea i think the problem is passing the value from the details function to the view .I am not  able to pass the value . @Claies

Comment: I am able to do that in search but not in detail  view

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: **Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<a href="#details/{{child.id}}">Details</a>
```

In router

```
  .when("/details/:id", {
 //
}
```

And in ctrl

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
        var id= $routeParams.id;
  JsonService.detail.get({

            details: id
        }, (response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
            $scope.details = response.data;

        })
```

Comment: Routeparams id is not passing in console log.I have updated the app .js in the quesstion please chheck